# No attribute "str" on dataframe when creating a plot

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, nlp

I filtered largest 5 tweets with max polarity after sentimental analysis.

```
maxx = df.nlargest(5,['polarity']).astype(str)
maxx
```

Output:

```
Unnamed: 0  clean_tweet Tweet_tokenized polarity    subjectivity    Sentiment_Type  scores  compound    sentiment_type  pca
315 315 Best of। luck Biden   best / luck biden   1.0 0.3 POSITIVE    {'neg': 0.0, 'neu': 0.122, 'pos': 0.878, 'comp...   0.802   POSITIVE    [-0.06151099614792966, -0.030998756958434074]
```

And now I'd like to create some `wordcloud` but I'm getting error:

```
hero.wordcloud(maxx, max_words=100)
```

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'
```

Comment: what package did you use for plotting the wordcloud

Comment: texthero im trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting based on polarity

```
df['polarity'] = df['polarity'].astype('float')   
maxx = df.nlargest(5, 'polarity')
```

If you are using `wordcloud` package try this

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud

text_data = ' '.join(maxx['clen_tweet']) 

wordcloud = WordCloud().generate(text_data)
plt.imshow(wordcloud2)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Using `texthero`

```
import texthero as hero

hero.wordcloud(maxx['clean_tweet'], max_words=100)
```

Comment: thanks, but i want only for 5 largest polarity tweet's. For all tweets is working

Comment: @whyimnotwhy, I hope dataframe 'maxx' has the 5 largest polarity tweets. Plotting with that dataframe will work. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: try maxx = df.nlargest(5, 'polarity') to sort dataframe based on polarity